# When environment is inconsistent for a period of time Nifi and kafka get out of sync and nifi starts reprocessing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

When nifi or kafka are down for an extended period of time, nifi decides to quit holding it's current position. When kafka comes back up, nifi begins to reprocess all data.

We don't end up LOSING data, but we do lose update/create flag.

What I suppose to do on to both sync finely and Nifi doesnt start process again.

Comment: How long is Nifi down? Kafka retains consumer offsets for offsets.retention.minutes (default 24 hours).

Comment: Well, in non prod we are testing. honestly we dont have any idea that how long they goes down whether nifi or kafka. but once kafka goes down nifi quit holding process and once it comes back nifi starts process again.                 It does retain consumer offsets.